# special rule of static_cast

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, static-cast

I've read [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) rules.

```
static_cast< new_type > ( expression )
```

...
   ...

5) If an implicit conversion sequence from new_type to the type of expression exists, 
      that does not include lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, function-to-pointer,
      null pointer, null member pointer, or boolean conversion, then static_cast can 
     perform the inverse of that  implicit conversion;

**Question** Can somebody explain or write example for this rule ?

Comment: no "Do my homework for me" questions.

Comment: It isn't my homework :) I can't understand this rule.

Comment: @Triton: There's nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an implicit conversion:

```
int n;
void *p = &n;   // OK: int* to void* is an implicit converion
```

The inverse conversion can't be done implicitly:

```
int *pi = p;    // ERROR
```

but, by that rule, can be done with `static_cast`:

```
int *pi = static_cast<int*>(p);  // OK
```

The rule lists some implicit conversions that can't be reversed with `static_cast`:

```
bool b = p;                       // OK: void* to bool can be implicit
void *p2 = static_cast<void*>(b); // ERROR: can't be undone with static_cast
```